# How does varbinary data sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I can `ORDER BY` over a `varbinary` column in MS SQL Server. I wonder what is algorithm behind this. I failed to find any official documentation on how does `varbinary` data is compared in SQL Server. I can guess rules it uses by experimenting but I do not want to base my solutions on guesses.

So does anybody know any details about the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for comparing and sorting binary data in SQL Server is basically the same as comparing byte arrays in general (each byte, left to right).  One difference in SQL Server is the concept of a NULL value, which results in an unknown compare result and causes NULL values to sorts before non-NULL values.

**UPDATE:**

Also, SQL Server ignores trailing binary zeros in binary string comparisons.

According to [this Connect feedback item](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48660/comparing-binary-0x-and-0x00-turns-out-to-be-equal-on-sql-server), SQL Server adheres to the ANSI SQL standard in comparing binary strings. Below is the relevant comment from Microsoft on the behavior.

> The behavior is actually by design and we follow the ANSI SQL
>   specification. See rules below from the latest spec (5c in
>   particular):
>
> 5) The comparison of two binary string values X and Y, neither of which is a binary large object string value, is determined as follows:
>
> a) Let Lx be the length in octets of X and let Ly be the length in
>   octets of Y. Let Xi, 1 (one) ≤ i ≤ Lx, be the value of the i-th octet
>   of X, and let Yi, 1 (one) ≤ i ≤ Ly, be the value of the i-th octet of
>   Y.
>
> b) If Lx = Ly and Xi = Yi, 1 (one) ≤ i ≤ Lx, then X is equal to Y.
>
> c) If Lx < Ly, Xi = Yi for all i ≤ Lx, and the right-most Ly – Lx
>   octets of Y are all X'00's, then it is implementation- defined whether
>   X is equal to Y or whether X is less than Y.
>
> d) If Lx < Ly, Xi = Yi for all i ≤ Lx, and at least one of the
>   right-most Ly – Lx octets of Y is not X'00', then X is less than Y.
>
> e) If Xj < Yj, for some j, 0 (zero) < j ≤ minimum(Lx, Ly), and Xi = Yi
>   for all i < j, then X is less than Y.
>
> Basically, the standard leaves it up to implementation to treat strings that differ only by 00 as equal or less. We treat it as equal.

I want to add that a byte here is the 8-bit unsigned raw value, similar to the byte type in .NET. This differs from Java, where a byte type is treated as a signed value.

Comment: Do you have any references to official documentation?

Comment: No official documentation of this behavior that I know of.  I think rules for comparing primitive byte arrays are well known so are not detailed in SQL documentation.

Comment: When you say "each byte, left to right", do you mean using signed or unsigned byte comparisons?

Comment: @Archie, unsigned. I'll update my answer to clarify.